# New Line doesn't ocured for html input button in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, newline

I have a Html Input button:

```
  <input id="Meal17" runat="server" type="button" style="height: 60px; width: 235px; display: block;" class="arrayinput" />
```

and now i want to set value for  it with JQuery :

```
  $("#Meal17").click(function (e) {
  $(this).val("hello" + "\n" + "this is test" );
}
```

now in INTERNET Explorer the new line in my button value dosn't ocured,why??how can i solve it.
thanks alot.

Comment: @ nevermind:it doesn't work in IE11 !

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake.... removed comment....

Comment: @Farna what about using `<div>` for this? [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4awef36u/).

Comment: @Fiddle example:thank you very much,i changed to <div>,it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `button` element instead and use `<br>` for a line break inside it:

```
<button id="Meal17" runat="server" type="button"
style="height: 60px; width: 235px; display: block;"
class="arrayinput">Hello<br>this is test</button>
```

Or, using jQuery as in your case,

```js
$("#Meal17").click(function (e) {
  $(this).html("hello<br>this is test" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Meal17" runat="server" type="button"
  style="height: 60px; width: 235px; display: block;" class="arrayinput">Dummy</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a [known problem](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2004/11/innerhtml_and_t.html) in Internet Explorer. As a workaround, insert a `<br>` element instead of a newline character.

Comment: Markup is ignored inside a `value` attribute/property.